# iOS detect if device is used as wifi hotspot

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, hotspot, tethering

I need to find out from my app, if the current device is used as personal wifi hotspot.
And if there is any way to know which is the iPhone local ip (on the hotspot network). I found that the iPhone set itself 172.20.10.1 address, but I'd like to retrive it programmatically.